# Enumeration elements not found

Tags: scala

I have this enumeration in Scala:

```
package genericGame

object Suit extends Enumeration {
  val Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds, Spades = Value
  type Suit = Value
}
```

And this abstract class using it:

```
package genericGame
abstract class Game(allCards: Deck = (2 to 14).flatMap(x => List(Card(x, Clubs), Card(x, Hearts), Card(x, Diamonds), Card(x, Spades)))) {}
```

The issue is that the elements of the enumeration are not recognised:

```
Cannot resolve symbol Clubs
Cannot resolve symbol Hearts
Cannot resolve symbol Diamonds
Cannot resolve symbol Spades
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `Suit.Clubs`, etc. or `import Suit._`.